# How to add classes in ReactJs dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I want one class to be toggled on `onClick`, the functionality that i want is whenever i click on the one of the icon it's color should get changed, (default color will be same for the both the icons but whenever I click one of the icons a `class` will be added and according to that class color should get changed and when I click again that class should get removed.)

```
import "./App.css";
import { BsCloudRain } from "react-icons/bs";
import { GiForest } from "react-icons/gi";

function App() {

  return (
      <div id="container">
        <div id="icons">
          <BsCloudRain className="rain" />
          <GiForest className="forest" />
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `React.useState`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `onClick` handler to your icon components.  Then create a function that takes the event target and accesses the `classList` to toggle the class you want to add.  This will remove the class when clicked again, if it's already on the list.

```
import "./App.css";
import { BsCloudRain } from "react-icons/bs";
import { GiForest } from "react-icons/gi";

function App() {
  const toggleClass = (e) => {
    e.target.classList.toggle("green")
  }

  return (
      <div id="container">
        <div id="icons">
          <BsCloudRain className="rain" onClick={toggleClass}/>
          <GiForest className="forest" onClick={toggleClass} />
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `className` property, despite the name, isn't necessarily one class-name: it can be zero, one, or more class-names, separated by spaces. So if you have a boolean `shouldIncludeRainClass`, then you can write

```
<BsCloudRain className={shouldIncludeRainClass ? 'rain' : ''} />
```

to get `className='rain'` when the boolean is true and `className=''` (meaning "no class") when it's false.